# Using async in app startup script not returning any results

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to run the following script in my Node app to check if any users exist and if not, create first admin user. Yet the script simply do nothing, return nothing even while using Try/Catch so can someone please tell me what I am missing / doing wrong here? or how I can possibly catch the error (if any)? Thanks

```
import pmongo from 'promised-mongo';
import crypto from 'crypto';

const salt = 'DuCDuUR8yvttLU7Cc4';

const MONGODB_URI = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/mydb';

const db = pmongo(MONGODB_URI, {
  authMechanism: 'ScramSHA1'
}, ['users']);


async function firstRunCheckAndCreateSuperAdmin(cb) {

  const username = 'admin2@test2.com';

  try {
     const user = await db.users.findOne({ role: 'admin'});
     console.log(user);
     if(!user) return cb('No user found');
  } catch(e) {
      cb('Unexpected error occurred');
  }

  if(!user) {
    console.log('No admin detected.');

    const adminPassword = crypto.pbkdf2Sync ( 'password', salt, 10000, 512, 'sha512' ).toString ( 'hex' );
    await db.users.update({username: username}, {$set: {username: username, password: adminPassword, role: 'admin'}}, {upsert: true});
  }

  db.close();
  process.exit();
}

firstRunCheckAndCreateSuperAdmin(function(err, resultA){
    if(err) console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: Does the script exit, or does it continue to run without printing anything?

Comment: Does the `findOne()` method return a Promise (which is needed for it to work with `await`)? I thought it takes a callback as a parameter.

Comment: I believe it returns a promise if there is no callback

Comment: @CalebEby If i added console.log just above the line const username... it will print it then exit, nothing else displayed

Comment: Why don't you try using a promise... `db.users.findOne(...).then(console.log)` What happens?

Comment: @CalebEby can you please provide an example? Thanks

Comment: @MChan under
`const username = 'admin2@test2.com';`
do
`db.users.findOne({ role: 'admin'}).then(console.log)`

Comment: @MChan Any specific reason you are using callback in `firstRunCheckAndCreateSuperAdmin`? `async` functions always return a Promise `async function f(x) { return x}; f(100).then(console.log)` Removing `cb` argument should simplify your code. After that you could remove all `try-catch` and `process.exit` and catch at the very end `firstRunCheckAndCreateSuperAdmin().then(log, log)`

Comment: @YuryTarabanko Thanks I tried the .then approach but unfortunately it didn't work :(

Comment: @MChan Thats totally unexpected. Could you plz show modified `firstRunCheckAndCreateSuperAdmin` code you have tried?

Comment: @YuryTarabanko  firstRunCheckAndCreateSuperAdmin().then(x => console.log(`Resolved: ${x}`)); and in the firstRunCheckAndCreateSuperAdmin function I will return await db.users.update...  On a minor note not sure if this will make any difference the script where all of this code is placed in a file under folder tools/superadmin.js, I then placed the file in Package.json under Scripts section >> "admin-check": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development babel-node tools/superadmin.js", and I run the script using npm run admin-check

Comment: @MChan a callback does not make sense inside of an async function. Callback hell resolved by promises, promise hell resolved by async await...

Answer (score 4):

You are not returning any callback when there is no admin user in the following code snippet

```
if (!user) {
    console.log('No admin detected.');

    const adminPassword = crypto.pbkdf2Sync ( 'password', salt, 10000, 512, 'sha512' ).toString ( 'hex' );
    await db.users.update({username: username}, {$set: {username: username, password: adminPassword, role: 'admin'}}, {upsert: true});

    // call cb(user) here
}
```

Comment: Thought about this, but console.log('No admin detected.'); is not printed in the first place, so I thought it is no use to return anything, make sense?

Answer (score 3):

Please see comment.

```
import pmongo from 'promised-mongo';
import crypto from 'crypto';

const salt = 'DuCDuUR8yvttLU7Cc4';

const MONGODB_URI = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/mydb';

const db = pmongo(MONGODB_URI, {
  authMechanism: 'ScramSHA1'
}, ['users']);


async function firstRunCheckAndCreateSuperAdmin(cb) {

  const username = 'admin2@test2.com';

  try {
    const user = await db.users.findOne({
      role: 'admin'
    });
    console.log(user);
    //(1) If user is undefined, then launch cb with an error message;
    if (!user) return cb('No user found');
  } catch (e) {
    //(2) If something is wrong, then launch cb with an error message;
    cb('Unexpected error occurred');
  }

  //This part of the code will only be reached if user is defined.
  //This is a dead code as if user is undefined, it would have exited at (1)
  if (!user) {
    console.log('No admin detected.');

    const adminPassword = crypto.pbkdf2Sync('password', salt, 10000, 512, 'sha512').toString('hex');
    await db.users.update({
      username: username
    }, {
      $set: {
        username: username,
        password: adminPassword,
        role: 'admin'
      }
    }, {
      upsert: true
    });
  }

  //So if user exists, it will close db and exit without calling cb.
  db.close();
  process.exit();
}

firstRunCheckAndCreateSuperAdmin(function(err, resultA) {
  if (err) console.log(err);
});
```

Note:

- If you are using async/await, then you don't need to use callback.
- If you are using callback, then you don't need to have a return statement.
- If the intention of the function is suppose to have a return value, make sure all code path returns a value.

Answer (score 2):

I have tried to rewrite your code to make it smaller and to remove all node-style callback types of async code from it. I replaced `update` with `insertOne` since you only have one user to insert (not multiple to update). Also I have added 500 ms timeout when calling `firstRunCheckAndCreateSuperAdmin` in case it "hangs". It should log something at the end :)

```
import pmongo from 'promised-mongo'
import crypto from 'crypto'
import {
  promisify
} from 'util'

const pbkdf2 = promisify(crypto.pbkdf2)

const salt = 'DuCDuUR8yvttLU7Cc4'

const MONGODB_URI = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/mydb'

const db = pmongo(MONGODB_URI, {
  authMechanism: 'ScramSHA1'
}, ['users']);

const username = 'admin2@test2.com'

async function firstRunCheckAndCreateSuperAdmin() {
  let user = await db.users.findOne({
    role: 'admin'
  });

  if (!user) { // no user lets create one
    user = await db.users.insertOne({
      username: username,
      password: (await pbkdf2('password', salt, 10000, 512, 'sha512')).toString('HEX'),
      role: 'admin'
    });
  }

  return user
}

const timeout = delay => message => new Promise((_, reject) => setTimeout(reject, delay, new Error(message)))

Promise
  .race([firstRunCheckAndCreateSuperAdmin(), timeout(500)('Rejected due to timeout')])
  .then(user => console.log(`Got user ${JSON.stringify(user)}`))
  .catch(error => console.error(error))
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, I've copied it and paste it, then tested it using the command 'npm run admin-check''. I've pasted error returned in https://jsfiddle.net/Lj64uknk/ as it is big. Thanks again for your help

Comment: @MChan `util.promisify` was introduced in version 8. You need to install [promisify-node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/promisify-node) and use it instead of `util.promisify`

Comment: Change import { promisify } from 'util';  -> to -> import { promisify } from 'promisify-node'; and still getting error TypeError: (0 , _promisifyNode.promisify) is not a function

Comment: @MChan You need to import default `import promisify from 'promisify-node'`

Comment: So we have a new error now, 'Error: Rejected due to timeout', Error: Rejected due to timeout at ....superadmin.js:39:90 where the line (const timeout = delay => message => new Promise((_, reject) => setTimeout(reject, delay, new Error(message)))) is

Comment: @MChan Well, atleast we found out that your database takes too long to respond :). I doubt it is ok that single user lookup takes half a second. Check if connection string is ok. Also you could [ping](https://github.com/gordonmleigh/promised-mongo#database-commands) database to see if is responding at all.

Comment: Sorry was my mistake regarding mongod, now I get error at line 36 password: (await pbkdf2....... [Error: No callback provided to pbkdf2]